# Add Ajax call on a div existing link

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, hyperlink

I have this :

```
<div id="div-for-ajax-onclick">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Link to google</a> 
</div> 

$("#div-for-ajax-onclick").click(function() {
// update database
});
```

I want that if somebody clicks the link to Google, it both : 
-> dynamically updates the database with AJAX,
-> AND ALSO keeps the normal link behaviour and sends them to Google.

Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. In this case what you'll have to do is prevent the default behavior of `a`. And do the `db` thing and then redirect or whatever like

```js
var link = document.querySelector("a");

link.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("save things in DB");
    
    window.location = e.target.href;
})
```

```html
<div id="div-for-ajax-onclick">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Link to google</a> 
</div>
```

If you've more than one `a` tags, you'll have to use `querySelectorAll("a")` and then loop through all to attach event listeners

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular `POST` request with jQuery where the user is redirected on the `success` function of the AJAX call. The `success` is called when the AJAX request receives an OK from the server, i.e. the database is updated. It is now safe to redirect the user to `www.google.com` using `window.location.href`.

The handling of the database update must be done with an API.

```js
function handleLinkClick(redirectURL) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "URL to your endpoint in the server",
    data: {}, // the data you want to send is placed here.
    success: () => {
      window.location.href = redirectURL;
    },
  });

};
```

```html
<div>
  <a onclick="handleLinkClick('www.google.com')" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by first making the POST to the database and then on success, open the URL to google as so

```
$.ajax({
  url: `${url}`,
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function () {
    // Now that the user's request has updated the database, that means that
    // this has been a success, now the next thing is to open the URL.
    window.open(url);
  }
})
```